# Puppeteer TimeoutError: When using multiple waitForFileChooser() on same page

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am working with Puppeteer and I have a page that requires  multiple image uploads to different inputs. I am using **page.waitForFileChooser()** for each input. The first **page.waitForFileChooser()** works and the image is uploaded. However, any following **page.waitForFileChooser()** causes a timeout error.

> TimeoutError: Waiting for `FileChooser` failed: 30000ms exceeded

```js
     // 1st Image Upload
     const [fileChooser] = await Promise.all([
         page.waitForFileChooser(),
         page.click('#inputOne'),
     ]);
    
     await fileChooser.accept(['imageOne.jpg']);


     // 2nd Image Upload
     const [fileChooserTwo] = await Promise.all([
         page.waitForFileChooser(),
         page.click('#inputTwo'),
     ]);
    
     await fileChooserTwo.accept(['imageTwo.jpg']);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**Update:** I was able to figure it out.

I assume it was a Race Condition issue. In order for it to function **await page.waitForTimeout()** was added.

**Working Multiple Image Uploader**

```js
     // 1st Image Upload
     const [fileChooser] = await Promise.all([
         page.waitForFileChooser(),
         await page.waitForTimeout(1000),
         await page.click('#inputOne'),
     ]);
    
     await fileChooser.accept(['imageOne.jpg']);


     // 2nd Image Upload
     const [fileChooserTwo] = await Promise.all([
         page.waitForFileChooser(),
         await page.waitForTimeout(1000),
         await page.click('#inputTwo'),
     ]);
    
     await fileChooserTwo.accept(['imageTwo.jpg']);
```